# how do I emulate read and update git global config file using gitPython?

Tags: python, git, git-config, gitpython

I want to reads git global config file using `git config --list`, so I can use to read and update the global config file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the ~/.gitconfig type config:

```
 globalconfig = git.GitConfigParser([os.path.normpath(os.path.expanduser("~/.gitconfig"))], read_only=True)
```

That's more or less what gitpython itself does, except it also uses "system" and "repo" level configs (where system is "/etc/gitconfig"), see

```
 def _get_config_path(self, config_level):
```

and

```
def config_reader(self, config_level=None):
```

in git/base.py in the source of gitpython

Answer (score 1):

[gitconfig](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gitconfig) may be exactly what you need.

Comment: So does `.gitconfig` always lies in user directory location ? I mean what if its location is different for a different user ?

Comment: The "user global" (as opposed to "system global") git config file may be in `~/.gitconfig`, but XDG now suggests that it should be in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` with `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` defaulting to `~/.config`.  Insert standard grumble about XDG here. :-)

Comment: This library package is an empty package and can not be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Since @unhammer posted their answer in 2014 `GitPython` has continued to evolve. Here is an example of how to read the global user name using Python 3 and `GitPython` v3.1.11:

```py
def git_user_name() -> str:
    from git import Repo
    reader = Repo(path=None).config_reader()
    field = reader.get_value("user", "name")
    return field
```

This works from any directory, a local repo is not required.