# Read and update git config with python?

Tags: python, git, configparser

I tried `configparser`, but it does not respect indentation for git config files (git config files have indentation inside sections as opposed to linux usual format without indentation). After I update config file, all indentation is gone.

There is similar question here: [how do I emulate read and update git global config file using gitPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048996/how-do-i-emulate-read-and-update-git-global-config-file-using-gitpython)

Though, I wonder if its possible to use native python to do same thing? Or `gitpython` is best alternative?

For example, before updating, config looks like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
```

After I update it with `configparser`, it looks like this:

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
test = 10
```

P.S. Suggested `gitconfig` library seems to not even exist. It does not install, saying its some sort of dummy project.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/GitPython/ : https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#module-git.config; https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+git+config

Comment: Why are you linking this? I asked if its possuble to do natively without external lib. Though will probably use gitpython

Comment: configparser does not like some of Git's entries, e.g., a line reading `[submodule "foo.bar"]` baffles it if I remember correctly. You could write your own Git configuration parser, and someone probably has done that.

Comment: Looks like gitpython has written good parser already. So will stick with it I guess

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me:

```
with repo.config_writer() as config:
    config.set_value("git-p4", "client", p4client)
```

Comment: Currently [the documentation](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#module-git.config) of GitPython is quite poor. Or maybe there's a bug? What is *git.config.GitConfigParser alias of git.config.GitConfigParser* supposed to mean?

Answer (score 3):

You can get any property from config file using:

```
repo = Repo(dir_of_repository)
user_name = repo.config_reader().get_value("user", "name")
```

Comment: It's worth adding that Repo can be imported using: from git import Repo